# filterable and sortable datatable/datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, filter, datatable

I have a huge table and I need to implement a (web) control to allow me to browse through all records, paginate, filter and sort them. My first thought is to implement a DataGrid/something and to put as DataSource a DataTable which is read (with a "view" or simple sql "select all" statement) and then to filter the DataTable object (DataView.RowFilter, etc). As far as I am aware, this sorting/filtering is done on the client-side, after all records are read. Is there any more elegant/efficient way to do this (meaning - just read the records you need from the database server)?

Comment: You say, "(web)" control. Are you using ASP.NET? Which version?

Comment: Thanks for the tag-suggestion. Yes, I am want to use it on web, but probably there has to be a similar way even for a desktop application.  I am using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: It won't be similar to a desktop application at all. The web is quite different.

Comment: I know. But the data objects (DataTable & co) are the same. Also, the desktop client might be miles away and fetching the entire table to do the sorting/filtering/pagination there each time might not be a good idea. That's why I tried to ask the question in a more general way ... maybe a non-web developer had a similar issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I saw you edited the tags ... I am also interested in pagination. I knew I am not allowed to put more than 5 tags and I decided to go with "pagination" instead of "asp.net" ...

Comment: I would look into controls that can use Linq and IQueryable as data sources, since Linq is a nice abstraction layer that can be backed by different providers, it can 'describe' filtering, sorting and paging via expressions and can fallback to in memory mode if IQueryable cannot be parsed natively by the provider.

Comment: The fact that you're using ASP.NET is more critical to your question than the fact that you're interested in pagination. In fact, it's absolutely critical.

Comment: The web situation is totally different. You clearly don't understand web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controls like GridView the default paging retrieves all rows from the database each time a page is selected.

Not exactly efficient is it? However, you can use custom paging to retrieve only those records you need for the currently selected page.

Here is an example: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/paging-and-sorting/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs

Comment: Well, your solution does what I have asked. However, I was hoping for a solution that requires a little bit less coding and a little bit more general. Anyway, thanks! :-)